# Ember: Dynamically created component actions don't fire

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having trouble with {{actions}} on Ember (1.11.0) components not being triggered when the component has been added to the page dynamically.  Oddly enough, it seems to be related to how the ember application has been added to the page - via the default template vs. added to a "rootElement".

Working JSBin: [actions are triggered](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mepocosugu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Non-Working JSBin: [actions aren't triggered](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qiriqolodi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

My Component Definition:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/foo-bar">
    <p>Component {{name}}</p>
    <button {{action "doIt"}}>Do It</button>  
</script>

App.FooBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    click: function() {
        console.log('click fired! - ' + this.get('name'));
    },
    actions: {
        doIt: function() {
            console.log('doIt fired! - ' + this.get('name'));
        } 
    }
});
```

The click() event and doIt() action aren't triggered when the component has been added to the page dynamically.  I'm using append() method to add the component to the page:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    count : 1,
    actions: {
        createNewFoobBar: function() {
            this.set('count', this.get('count') + 1);
            var comp = this.container.lookup('component:foo-bar');
            comp.set('name', this.get('count'));
            comp.set('controller', this);
            comp.append();
        }
    }
});
```

In either case, actions are properly triggered when the component is part of the template:

```
{{foo-bar name="one"}}
```

Comment: I am able to get the click() event to fire on the component in my previous JSBin example by changing the append( ) call to
    appendTo('#content')
However the component's action still doesn't work as expected.
[jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fojitukere/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it works if:

- `comp.appendTo('#content')` is used instead `comp.append()`,
- `comp.set('controller', this);` is removed, otherwise error is thrown.

Working jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/saquzupaye/edit?html,js,console,output

Why does `comp.append()` not working? We could see that components are  appended to `body` instead of `#content`, and this behavior looks like unexpected, since `rootElement: "#content"` is defined.

**From Guides:**

"...The rootElement can be either a DOM element or a jQuery-compatible selector string. Note that views appended to the DOM outside the root element will not receive events. If you **specify a custom root element**, make sure you only append views inside it!" (from [Event delegation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#toc_event-delegation) guide)

"...At the end of the rendering process, the root view asks the RenderBuffer for its element. The RenderBuffer takes its completed string and uses jQuery to convert it into an element. The view assigns that element to its element property and places it into the correct place in the DOM (the location specified in appendTo **or the application's root element if the application used append**)." (from [UnderstandingEmber: The view Layer](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/) guide).

So my opinion is that **it's bug**, and workaround is to append to root element manually by using `appendTo()`.

Comment: Thanks Artych.  The append behavior does appear to be a bug according to the document you quoted.